# mysql - how to merge two tables based on a column?

Tags: mysql, join, merge

I have two tables, `table1` and  `table2`

```
table1
    id |    val    |
    a  |           |
    a  |           |
    b  |           |
    b  |           |

table2
    id |    val    |
    a  |    2      |
    a  |    3      |
    b  |    1      |
    b  |    0      |
    c  |    5      |        
    d  |    2      |        
    d  |    -2     |
```

I want to fill up the values `val` of `table1` based on the value of `table2` in order to get:

```
table1
    id |    val    |
    a  |    2      |
    a  |    3      |
    b  |    1      |
    b  |    0      |
```

This what I am doing

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id;
```

but what I am getting is a table with four columns repeating each values twice.

Comment: You cant. How you difference between both `a` and both `b` ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Excuse me, I did not understand the question...

Comment: well that make it two of us, because I dont understand the logic of your question neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If val is nullable:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tab1.id, ifnull(tab1.val, tab2.val) AS val
FROM tab1
JOIN tab2 ON tab1.id = tab2.id
```

If val is not null:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tab1.id, if(tab1.val = '', tab2.val, tab1.val) AS val
FROM tab1
JOIN tab2 ON tab1.id = tab2.id
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but why the values are repeated twice?

Comment: OK updated. however if you have values in table1, you might use UNION instead

Answer (score 0):

This is the only interpretation of your query which makes sense to me.  We can retain records from `table2` depending on whether or not their `id` values be present in `table1`:

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.val
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT id
    FROM table1
) t1
    ON t2.id = t1.id
```